# How to make data loosely coupled with application code?

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, tightly-coupled-code

I have inherited a project code base from a developer who worked on it.
I have to make some changes in it.

Say I have a table "CARS" with 2 columns

ID | CARNAME

1  |  HYUNDAI
2  |  FORD
3  |  BMW

bound to a Model class "Car":

```
public Class Car{

  @Id
  @Column(name="ID")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name="FORD")
  private String carName;

  //getters and setters...
}
```

and in my code snippet (say in some controller class) I have to see whether 
the given car is a FORD car, the conditional code would be something like

`if(thisCar.getCarName()=="FORD")`

or

`if(thisCar.getId()==2L)`

but this creates some dependency issues between DB and app. 
what if I flush the cars table or restructure it and as a result FORD car 
entry goes at primary-key 3 
same goes for string "FORD". what if tomorrow it changes to "FORDspeed" or something.
I would have to change my code accordingly.

how do I make my code loosely coupled in this sense from data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not rely on field **ID**, because this may has changed as you said. So, phrase `if(thisCar.getId()==2L)` may has different result later time, so you should avoid it. But I think `if(thisCar.getCarName()=="FORD")` always has a static result and I think it has not any problem based on object oriented design.

Comment: still it feels something wrong . We're still hardcoding "FORD" STRING

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I think this is unavoidable. You need to check the car name with a hardcoded string.

Comment: How about keeping another layer in between code and table ?
some properties file or something ?